# How can I disable an Angular Material tooltip for certain screen sizes?

Tags: angular, tooltip, breakpoints, angular-material2

Say I have a [tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) on a [button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview), and I'm hiding the button's text label for mobile in lieu of the tooltip:

```
<button md-button mdTooltip="Neat tooltip message" [mdTooltipDisabled]=" ??? ">
    <md-icon>neat_icon</md-icon> <span fxShow.xs="false">Neat Button Label</span>
</button>
```

How can I disable the tooltip when at `gt.xs`, for example? There must be a way to access the current size range, but I can't find it.

**References**

- [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API)
- [Breakpoints](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/BreakPoints)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObservableMedia` and `MediaChange` from `@angular/flex-layout` can be used to `subscribe` to an `observable` that returns current screen size.

In the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xwtwIJG1BYOhRuw8d63r?p=preview) code, I am hiding the tooltip for `sm` and `xs`.

component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MediaChange, ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-position-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-position-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-position-example.css'],
})

export class TooltipPositionExample {

  disableTooltip: boolean = false;

  constructor(media: ObservableMedia) {
      media.asObservable()
        .subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
        console.log(change.mqAlias);
          if(change.mqAlias == 'sm' || change.mqAlias == 'xs'){
            this.disableTooltip = true;
          }
          else{
            this.disableTooltip = false;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button md-button class="example-tooltip-host" mdTooltip="Neat tooltip message" 
        mdTooltipPosition="above"
        [mdTooltipDisabled]="disableTooltip">
  Tooltip Test Button
</button>
```

[flex-layout ObservableMedia Doc](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia)

Hope this helps!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ObservableMedia

From this link, I used the second example `(2) ObservableMedia::asObservable()`

Comment: AM docs have no reference to it. I just searched within the flex-layout docs for hints.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to get it working on load by a statement inside `ngOnInit()`: `if (this.media.isActive('xs')) { ... }` That, in conjunction with your suggestion, work beautifully.